# How to select pickList or order shuttle in CRM application using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, crm

I am trying to automate CRM application. It has attribute selection panel which is known as "order shuttle" or "pick list". we should select from "Available Fields" to "Selected Fields". Is there any way to automate this feature in Selenium WebDriver? If not, any workaround?

note: It's not a drop-down or combo box or drop-down multi-select.

Really appreciate your help and thanks for the time in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you share that CRM URL or screenshot of element with which you want to interact?

Comment: Relevant HTML and code trials please.

Comment: Is it draggable items from Available Fields to Selected Fields?

Comment: Updated the image

Comment: @Murthi no. drag and drop is not an operation